# SQL PHP my admin error on using subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

Hello I am trying to write a query that shows the following.
My EV table is as follows:

```
John 100
Mark 120 
John 100


My PR table is as follows: 
Marie 67
John 100

The output should be like this: 

Name     UID    Total_EV    TOTAL_PR
John     100       2           1
Marie    67        0           1 
Mark     120       1           0 
Jackie   50        0           0
```

I have tried this code and it is just outputting the total records in the EV and PV table, so it is listing the same Total_EV and Total_PR for everyone.

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.UID, 
(select count(b.uid) from EV b, Members a where 
a.uid = b.uid) as TotalEvents,
(select count(b.uid)  from PR b, Members a where 
a.uid = b.uid) as TotalPractices
FROM Members c group by c.UID
```

Any help would be appreciated please!

Answer (score 1):

This means that you do not have a column with the name 'f.UID' in your table (Members c).
If you have the columns f.UID in your table, make sure you spell the name correctly, table name is not written in the correct way. You should either rename your table in order not to have space or try [Members c] with brackets.

Comment: f is what I renamed the first subquery so it technically doesn't exist in the members' table.